# Return result to caller batch file

Tags: batch

I have two batch files A.bat and B.bat.

A.bat

```
@echo off
set str1=1,2,3,4,5
set str2=6,7,8,9
call B.bat %str1% %str2%
```

B.bat

```
@echo off
set str1=%1
set str2=%2
set str3=%str1%,%str2%
```

Expected that B.bat return `%str3%` (means 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) back to A.bat file
So that A.bat used the result for further processing.

Comment: What are you having issues with?

Comment: I don't know how B.bat return value to A.bat and how A.bat will catch the value?

Answer (score 3):

We need to pass one extra variable from A.bat to B.bat

A.bat

```
@echo off
set str1=1,2,3,4,5
set str2=6,7,8,9
set str3=
call B.bat %str1% %str2% %str3% >nul
echo str3 %str3%
```

B.bat

```
@echo off
set str1=%1
set str2=%2
set str3=%str1%,%str2%
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer after some time and also consider indenting multiple lines of code. That way you will get these code blocks instead of just a highlighting that's as long as the line.